# TypeScript: Getting an error 'Options' type is not compatible with 'NavigateOptions' in Next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js, navigation, next-router

My code block:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

interface Options {
  scroll: boolean;
}

const Component = () => {
  const router = useRouter();


  const updateSearchParams = () => {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

    const newPathname = `${window.location.pathname}?${searchParams.toString()}`;

    const options: Options = { scroll: false };

    router.push(newPathname, options);
  };

  return (
  );
};

export default Component;
```

In the code example above, I'm getting a type incompatibility error in TypeScript. I've created a type called 'Options' and used it to create an object. However, it seems like the router.push function is expecting a 'NavigateOptions' type, leading to a type mismatch error.

```
router.push(newPathname, { scroll: false });
```

When I try the above code, I'm encountering a TypeScript error that says:

> Argument of type '{ scroll: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'NavigateOptions'. Object literal may only specify known
> properties, and 'scroll' does not exist in type 'NavigateOptions'.

Is this Next.js problem or am I doing something wrong?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nex-js",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "export": "next export",
    "lint": "eslint --fix \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\"",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\"",
    "build:icons": "tsc -b src/iconify-bundle && node src/iconify-bundle/bundle-icons-react.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.14",
    "@types/node": "20.2.1",
    "@types/react": "18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "next": "13.4.12",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.2.1",
    "@types/react": "18.2.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.55.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.55.0",
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.7.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "1.1.2",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "3.5.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "prettier": "2.8.4",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@emotion/react/@emotion/babel-plugin/@babel/core": "7.21.5",
    "@emotion/react/@emotion/babel-plugin/@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx/@babel/core": "7.21.5"
  }
}
```

It was solved like this but I couldn't understand it:

I looked to see if there was a type for scroll in `node_modules`, and I saw that there was a type, and it was solved. I couldn't understand it, but it was solved.

Comment: What is the definition of `router`?

Comment: @kelsny Since the code was too long, I edited it in a shortened form. I did not add any definition for the `router`.

Comment: Sounds like "scroll" is not a valid field for the options argument. What happens if you just remove it?

Comment: When you remove it, the scroll problem in this link: [https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49087](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49087) appears. I found the solution here, but I couldn't figure out how typescript works.

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#routerpush), you are passing your `options` in place of `as`

pass your options in third param

```
// syntax in Next docs
router.push(url, as, options)

// your code
router.push(newPathname, options);

// Maybe use it like this
// second param accepts a string that will be shown in the user's browser
router.push(newPathname, newPathname, options);
```

Comment: I looked to see if there was a type for scroll in `node_modules`, and I saw that there was a type, and it was solved. I couldn't understand it, but it was solved.